# How to loop through attributes and an array to create a table in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a survey, and have a bunch of columns named `:movie_1` through `:movie_5` that I would like to loop through to make a table in my form. What is the best way to do so?

So far I have started out as below, but can't figure out how to format the loop.

**survey.rb** model

```
attr_accessible :movie_1, :movie_2, :movie_3, :movie_4, :movie_5

MOVIES = ["Rocky", "Wayne's World", "The Godfather", "Alien", "Toy Story"]
```

**new.html.erb** survey form

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f|
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Movie Name</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
    </r>
    <% 5.times.each do |n| %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label Survey::MOVIES[n] %></th> # how can I loop through the MOVIES array?
        <th><%= f.text_field :movie_n %></th> # how can I loop through the different columns?
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% Survey::MOVIES.each_with_index do |movie, index| %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= f.label movie %></th>
    <th><%= f.text_field "movie_#{index+1}".to_sym %></th>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

However mind.blank is right: it's bad design to have `movie_1`, `movie_2`, etc fields in your survey model. It would make much more sense to have a movie model that belongs to a survey.

Comment: Thanks @Mischa, this is perfect. Yeah, I might end up making the second model. I'm going to have a bunch of different kinds of questions (text, integer, boolean), and thought it might be quicker to write everything into the view.

Comment: You're welcome. The drawback of your current way is that you have to change your database if you decide that users can rate a sixth movie. That shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you might want to consider making another model `Movie` which belongs to `Survey` and then use nested forms to display all the movies / update them.

There's a few good [railscasts here about nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+forms).

Comment: Thanks @mind.blank. Yeah, I've seen that railscast and have been contemplating maybe doing that. It just seems it might be quicker to just write a survey directly into the view file.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the column and just use those, that match the naming pattern.

example

```
Survey.columns.select{|c| c if c =~ /movie_[0-9]/}.each { |movie_column| puts movie_column }
```

But the better solution would be to have the correct relations setup, like *mind.blank* describes.

Comment: Sweet. I'll keep the `.select` in mind for when I have additional columns that I want to avoid. THanks!